# Unable to get tag names

Tags: php, evernote

I'm able to 'getNote' from guid but I'm not able to view tag names. getTagNames comes back as NULL. Am I using this function correctly?

```
    <?php
    $token = 'user-token';

    $sandbox = true;
    $china   = false;

    $client = new \Evernote\Client($token, $sandbox, null, null, $china);


    $Note = $client->getNote( 'note-guid' );

    $tagNames = $Note->getTagNames();

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump( $tagNames );
    echo '</pre>';
    ?>
```

Comment: What programming language is this? php?

Comment: Sorry, yes this is PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are using the wrong function. The correct name is [`getNoteTagNames`](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getNoteTagNames). This operation is performed off the `NoteStore`, not the `Note` struct.

UPDATE: It looks like you should try using the advanced client.

```
$advancedClient = new \Evernote\AdvancedClient($token, $sandbox);
```

From that, you should be able to get the `NoteStore`, and then perform the function I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$advancedClient = new \Evernote\AdvancedClient($token, $sandbox);    
$noteStore = $advancedClient->getNoteStore();    
$tags = $noteStore->getNoteTagNames($token,$noteGuid);
```

Returns an array of tags.